# how can I make that the shaded part is a little lighter than the rest?

Tags: shading

I want to draw one figure as follows

[image]

but how can I make that the shaded part what I marked in red is a little lighter than the rest? or use dashed line for that part?

my MWE is as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw (0,-5) -- (0,5);
  \fill (0,0) coordinate (o) node[anchor=north east]{$O$};
  
  \draw[fill=Green,opacity=0.3,] (1,2.5) -- (1,-1.5) node[text=black,opacity=1,below,xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]{$W$}-- (-1,-2.5) -- (-1,1.5) -- cycle;
  \draw[mydarkblue, line width=1pt] (3,-1.5) node[above,text=black]{$L$} -- (-2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I changed:

- Draw the line segment behind plane, then the plane, then the line segment in front of plane. (You may want to do similar things to the horizontal axis line.)
- Fill the plane in light green `fill=Green!30` and adjust the opacity `opacity=.8`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{mydarkblue}{blue!50!black}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw (0,-5) -- (0,5);
  \fill (0,0) coordinate (o) node[anchor=north east]{$O$};
  
  \draw[mydarkblue, line width=1pt] (-2,1) -- (0,0);
  \draw[fill=Green!30, opacity=.8] 
    (1,2.5) -- (1,-1.5)
      node[text=black, opacity=1, below, xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.5cm] {$W$}
    -- (-1,-2.5) -- (-1,1.5) -- cycle;
  \draw[mydarkblue, line width=1pt] (3,-1.5) node[above,text=black] {$L$} -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, but can find the way to make shaded part automaticlly in stead of drawing the line separately?

Comment: The `tikz` package itself doesn't support real 3d plotting and filling. You may take a look at [Sketch](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/). I haven't used it before and note it's no longer being maintained since 2012.

Comment: OK, anyway thanks, nice weekend